# How would i find a range of numbers inside of an array that suit a condition?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand arrays better and I've found this piece of code on this website that fills an array with a load of random numbers. I was wondering how you would go about, say, extracting a range of numbers. So if i wanted to find out how many of these random numbers inside of the array, were between 25 and 50, how would i go about doing this? I've heard about the Array.FindAll<> however i have no clue on how to use it. 
Thank you in advance.

```
Random r = new Random();

int count = 100;
// Create an array with count elements.
int[] numbers = new int[count];

// Loop over each index
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // Generate and store a random number at current index
    numbers[i] = r.Next(1, 100);
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with linq

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ you can try the following:

```
var numbersInRange = numbers.Where(number => number > 25 && number < 60)
                            .ToArray();
```

The above will filter out all the numbers in the range `(25,60)`. If you want to get also the numbers that are equal to either 25 or 60, you just have to use `>=` and `<=` repsectively.

If you don't want to use LINQ (which I couldn't explain), you could try the following:

```
var numbersInRange = new List<int>();
foreach(var number in numbers)
{
    if(number > 25 && number < 60)
    {
        numbersInRange.Add(number);
    }
}
```

So at the end you would have a list that would contains your numbers.

Comparing this to the LINQ version, I think that LINQ is the winner in simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq it is a single line

```
int[] inRange = numbers.Where(x => x >= 25 && x <= 50).ToArray();
```

The [Enumerable methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) are a collection of methods that operates on sequences of values and apply a predicate expression (x => 25 && x <= 50) to each member (x) of the sequence (numbers). In your particular case the [Where method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) filters the sequence based on the result of the boolean expression (the return includes the members where the expression returns true).

Answer (score 1):

Although "Linq" can do the job as shown by other answers ; there is also, as you heard about, [`Array.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.110).aspx) which behaves the same but already returns an array (and so doesn't need a call to `ToArray`)

```
int[] matchedNumbers = Array.FindAll (currentNumber => 25 <= currentNumber && currentNumber <= 50);
```

As for the "strange" arrow notation it's a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We can use Linq. First have `using System.Linq` in your namespaces so the extension methods are available.

To find the numbers:

```
numbers.Where(x => x >= 25 & x <= 50)
```

This takes a lambda expression (in this case `x => x >= 25 & x <= 50`) that takes on object of the type in the sequence (in this case `int`) returns `bool` and then evaluates for that expression for all contained items, filtering out those that do not.

You can use `ToArray()` on the result to get it back into an array, or just work on the results directly.

To get which numbers, that is to say, which indices the matches where at, you can use:

```
numbers.Select((x, i) => new {El = x, Idx = i}).Where(x => x.EL >= 25 & x.El <= 50).Select(x => x.Idx)
```

This first creates a new anonymous object for each item where `El` is the value held and `Idx` is the index it was at. Then it does the same `Where` as before, but on the `El` property of the object we created in the first step. Finally it extracts out the `Idx` property of the survivors so we have all of the matching indices.